# Mergesort with an inversion counter

Tags: beginner, mergesort, lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to Lisp and I'm yet to wrap my head around the lisp way of writing programs. Any comments regarding approach, style, missed opportunities appreciated:

*In particular*, please advice if I build results list correctly (`(setf merged-list (append merged-list (list a)))`).

```
;;;; Count inversions
(defun small-list (list)
  (or (null list) (null (rest list))))

(defun split-in-half (list)
  (let ((mid (ceiling (length list) 2)))
    (values (subseq list 0 mid)
            (subseq list mid))))

(defun count-inversions (list)
  (if (small-list list) (list list 0)
    (multiple-value-bind (lower upper) (split-in-half list)
      (merge-inversions
        (count-inversions lower)
        (count-inversions upper)))))

(defun merge-inversions (lower-pair upper-pair)
  (let ((lower (first lower-pair))
        (upper (first upper-pair))
        (merged-list '())
        (num-inversions 0))
    (loop while (not (and (null lower) (null upper)))
          do (cond
               ((null lower) (let ((a (first upper)))
                               (setf merged-list (append merged-list (list a)))
                               (setf upper (rest upper))))
               ((null upper) (let ((a (first lower)))
                               (setf merged-list (append merged-list (list a)))
                               (setf lower (rest lower))))
               ((< (first lower)
                   (first upper)) (let ((a (first lower)))
                   (setf merged-list (append merged-list (list a)))
                   (setf lower (rest lower))) )

               (t (let ((a (first upper)))
                    (setf merged-list (append merged-list (list a)))
                    (setf upper (rest upper))
                    (incf num-inversions (length lower))))))
    (list merged-list (+ (second lower-pair) (second upper-pair) num-inversions)))
```

Comment: @RTOSkit, As I said, I need advice on how to make my lisp better. The program does what it needs to do, however there is certainly ways to make it more concise, efficient, elegant. I would like to learn them.

Comment: No docstrings!!

Comment: An explanation of what this code is doing would be appreciated. Also, I see you don't declare any types.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, the code is aimed at counting inversions on a list, that is each situation when an element lower in the list is greater than an element higher in the list. Regarding types, could you please elaborate, as I mentioned I'm new to Lisp, and might easily be missing something obvious.

Comment: @zzandy: I think adding type declarations is used when you want to improve performance and/or when you want to add some typing to improve error checking of your code. (Specifically, for many operations, simple vectors are faster than linked lists.) However, performance considerations may not apply in your case. Most lisp books have sections on this topic. It is in the Common Lisp standard. Could you add a usage example for your code that the reader could run?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: The code is used simply as `(count-inversions list-of-like-100000-integers)`. I've read about type declarations, though I think it's a bit too advanced for me. Any advice appreciated though.

Comment: @zzandy: No, type declarations are nothing special. You can read about them in [Practical Common Lisp: Subsection Make It Work, Make It Right, Make It Fast](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/conclusion-whats-next.html). This is not detailed enough to use as a reference, but I think he explains the basic ideas well enough. There is of course much other information about this available on the net and in other books.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: thanks, I'll definitely read that. I'm currently oscillating between "Make It Work" and "Make It Right"

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 7 → 2. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use [`nconc`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nconc.htm) instead of `append` for speed in

   (setf merged-list (append merged-list (list a)))

   Note that you need `setf` with `nconc` only if `merged-list` is nil.
2. Use [`pop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_pop.htm): instead of

   (let ((a (first lower)))
     (setf merged-list (append merged-list (list a)))
     (setf lower (rest lower))))

   you can write

   (setf merged-list (nconc merged-list (list (pop lower))))
3. The combination of `let` and `loop` creates extra indentation for no good reason. You can use `with` clause in `loop` to create bindings instead, or use the [`do`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm) macro.
4. Usually *predicates* are named with a *-p* suffix, so I suggest that you rename your `small-list` to `small-list-p`.
5. Please fix line breaks and indentation in the third `cond` clause.

Comment: Thanks, that's a reply I was hoping for. I've changed indentation in third clause, I that what you meant?

Comment: @zzandy: looks good now (I added another small thing, see #3)

Answer (score 0):

- using *multiple values* instead of lists for return values
- merge-inversions has four parameters
- using multiple-value-call
- using LOOP functionality to *collect* items and to *sum* values
- much less traversal of lists

Try this:

```
(defun small-list-p (list)
  (not (and list (rest list))))

(defun split-in-half (list)
  (values (loop repeat (ceiling (length list) 2) collect (pop list))
          list))

(defun merge-inversions (lower lower-n upper upper-n &aux (num-inversions 0))
  (values (loop while (or lower upper)
                collect (cond ((null lower) (pop upper))
                              ((null upper) (pop lower))
                              ((< (first lower) (first upper)) (pop lower))
                              (t (incf num-inversions (length lower)) (pop upper))))
          (+ lower-n upper-n num-inversions)))

(defun count-inversions (list)
  (if (small-list-p list)
      (values list 0)
    (multiple-value-bind (lower upper)
        (split-in-half list)
      (multiple-value-call #'merge-inversions
        (count-inversions lower)
        (count-inversions upper)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Revised version using @sds's suggestions:

```
(defun small-list-p (list)
  (or (null list) (null (rest list))))

(defun split-in-half (list)
  (let ((mid (ceiling (length list) 2)))
    (values (subseq list 0 mid)
            (subseq list mid))))

(defun count-inversions (list)
  (if (small-list-p list) (list list 0)
    (multiple-value-bind (lower upper) (split-in-half list)
      (merge-inversions
        (count-inversions lower)
        (count-inversions upper)))))

(defmacro move-last (source target)
  `(setf ,target (nconc ,target (list (pop ,source)))))
```

Function `MERGE-INVERSIONS`:

```
(defun merge-inversions (lower-pair upper-pair )
  (loop 
    with lower = (first lower-pair)
    with upper = (first upper-pair)
    with merged-list = '()
    with num-inversions = 0
    while (not (and (null lower) (null upper)))
    do (cond
         ((null lower) (move-last upper merged-list))
         ((null upper) (move-last lower merged-list))
         ((< (first lower) (first upper)) (move-last lower merged-list))
         (t
          (move-last upper merged-list)
          (incf num-inversions (length lower)) ))
    finally (return (list merged-list
                          (+ (second lower-pair)
                             (second upper-pair)
                             num-inversions)))))
```

Performance went from this

```
139.740 seconds of real time
80,080,445,136 bytes consed
```

to this:

```
26.411 seconds of real time
87,009,536 bytes consed
```

---

<sub>This "answer" was extracted from Rev 7 of the question.</sub>